# Event not fired on datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker **inline**, when i `click on a year`, it is fine as i see ***ciao*** in `console`, however, when I click on `prev` or `next`, and then I `click` on a year, `console` is not showing ***ciao***. I have tried a lot of different things, one of which is the following and `goDateClick()` is firing but not the `click event` within it

```
  goDateClick();

  $("#sandbox-container .prev").on("click", function(e) {
    goDateClick();
  });

  $("#sandbox-container .next").on("click", function(e) {
    goDateClick();
  });

  function goDateClick() {
    $("#sandbox-container span").on("click", function(e) {
       console.log("ciao");
    });
  };
```

Try it, click a year and it's fine, click next or prev and the year won't show up

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vwmHF/233/)

I have tried the suggested answer as per "duplicated" and it doesn't work check http://jsfiddle.net/vwmHF/281/

Comment: Is the problem that you can't select the `.prev` and `.next` elements properly? Can you post the HTML?

Comment: I can select .prev or .next, but the year change in the html and then it is not more picking it up @CertainPerformance

Comment: Could u please check if there span exist after next previous click?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes it exists indeed

Comment: basically it's like the event callback isn't working on the inline calendar as I have followed their doc with no success http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html

Comment: `$(document)).on("click", "#sandbox-container .prev", function(e) {
    goDateClick();
  });`

Comment: @connexo check http://jsfiddle.net/vwmHF/246/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find a minimal code which only used datepicker events please view the snippet below :

[click to view demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mue7hcp5/1/)

```
$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy",
  viewMode: "years", 
  minViewMode: "years",
}).on('changeYear', function(e) {
  $('#my_date').text(e.date.getFullYear());
});
```

so here I just used the default `on('changeYear', function(e){})` to trigger whenever we click on the year.

Comment: oh thank you! That's actually what I was trying, I didn't see getFullyear, link to a doc pelase?

Comment: it's a javascript date function you can find it here [Javascript Date Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Comment: oh right didn't think of using plain js functions, thought to just follow the plugin doc, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating new listeners every time, only add a single listener to the container, and then select `e.target` to get the element that was clicked on. Replace the whole script with this:

```
document.querySelector('.datepicker').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'SPAN') return;
  document.querySelector('#my_year').textContent = e.target.textContent;
  e.target.classList.add('selected_year', 'active', 'focused');
});
```

Comment: please update snippet to working example.  The snippet is not functioning now.

Comment: Forgot to clarify - replace the entire original script with just this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use native bootstrap-datepicker's events 
[changedate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) and 
[changeyear](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changeyear)

and here is the changed code [in js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwmHF/316/)

```
$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy",
  viewMode: "years", 
  minViewMode: "years"
}).on("changeDate", function(e) {
   goDateClick(e)
}).on("changeYear", function(e) {
   goDateClick(e)
});

function goDateClick(e) {
    $this = $(e.target)
     $("#my_year").text($this.text());
    $("#sandbox-container span").removeClass("selected_year").removeClass("focused").removeClass("active");
    $this.attr("class", "selected_year").addClass("active focused");
};
```

You can see that I added .on("changeDate") and .on("changeYear") and pass event objects to your cutom function. And in your function goDateClick there is no need to add on-click handler as the event already handled by bootstrap-datepickers's native events. Only proper handling of e and e.target is needed.